# java.util.InputMismatchException scanner issue?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am trying to collect user input via the keyboard scanner and verifying if the input matches the stored value. So if the input is `2927942074l` the line `Correct` should appear however I get the following error. Also if the input doesn't match with the pin the line `Wrong` appears. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextLong(Scanner.java:2373)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextLong(Scanner.java:2328)
    at app.main(app.java:11)
```

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

class app {
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    long pin = 2927942074l;

    System.out.println("Please enter your pin.");
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    long input = keyboard.nextLong();

    if (input != pin)
    System.out.println("Wrong");
    if (input == pin)
    System.out.println("Correct");
  }
}
```

Comment: Input the value without the character "L". By calling `nextLong()` you already define that the given value will be a long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct and works as per requirement.

The thing that you need to input is `2927942074` not `2927942074l`

Answer (score 0):

Type just the number `2927942074` without trailing 'l'. Else it will treat it as a String.
Also you may want to add a condition using keyboard.hasNextLong() if you dont want to take String inputs.

```
if (keyboard.hasNextLong()) {
        long input = keyboard.nextLong();
        if (input != pin)
            System.out.println("Wrong");
        if (input == pin)
            System.out.println("Correct");
} else {
        System.out.println("Enter a valid pin");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to input

```
2927942074
```

not

```
2927942074l
```

The "L" is only for the Java Compiler to understand, that die digits resemble a long and not an int (which would be default).